# Maven + AspectJ weaving for Java8

Tags: maven, java-8, aspectj, aspectj-maven-plugin

I Cannot **mvn package** with the minimal sample below. Eclipse (Mars.2 Release 4.5.2) compiles and weaves without a problem.

What do I have to do to make it work?

The output:

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ test ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to ...\workspace\test\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] .../workspace/test/src/main/java/test/Foo.java:[6,21] cannot find symbol
  symbol: method doSomethingInjected()
```

A sample class:

```
package test;

public class Foo {
    public void bar() {
        this.doSomethingInjected();
    }
}
```

Sample interface:

```
package test;

public interface Injectable { }
```

aspect:

```
package test;

public aspect Injection {

    declare parents : test..* implements Injectable;

    public void Injectable.doSomethingInjected() {
        System.out.println("done");
    }
}
```

pom.xml (relevant parts as per  [aspectj-maven-plugin usage doc](http://www.mojohaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/usage.html))

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.9</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.9</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this, it makes your project compile and run cleanly (I tested it):

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>de.scrum-master.stackoverflow</groupId>
  <artifactId>aspectj-introduce-method</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.source-target.version>1.8</java.source-target.version>
    <aspectj.version>1.8.10</aspectj.version>
  </properties>

  <build>

    <plugins>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>${java.source-target.version}</source>
          <target>${java.source-target.version}</target>
          <!-- IMPORTANT -->
          <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
        <configuration>
          <!--<showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>-->
          <source>${java.source-target.version}</source>
          <target>${java.source-target.version}</target>
          <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
          <complianceLevel>${java.source-target.version}</complianceLevel>
          <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
          <!--<verbose>true</verbose>-->
          <!--<warn>constructorName,packageDefaultMethod,deprecation,maskedCatchBlocks,unusedLocals,unusedArguments,unusedImport</warn>-->
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <!-- IMPORTANT -->
            <phase>process-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
              <goal>test-compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>

  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
      <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: Two questions: how would I configure it in maven if my aspect(s) are in the test-jar? Secondly, why exactly are two lines marked <!-- Important --> ? I haven't been able to find any explanation about why exactly those are necessary.

Comment: Question #2: Those were notes to myself because in order to use incremental compilation you have to set it to false, see this [bug ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCOMPILER-209) for Maven Compiler. Setting the phase to "process-sources" for AspectJ Maven helps avoid certain problems if other code is compiled with Maven Compiler. The default phase is "compile", but "process-sources" is better in most cases (earlier). I do not want to go into more detail here in a comment.

Comment: Question #1: You would add the test-jar as a test dependency for the module in which you want to use it and then refer to it from AspectJ Maven's `aspectLibraries` section. Probably you would then define two separate plugin configs/executions for `compile` and `test-compile` so as to avoid your test aspects ending up in production. But I am not sure if that is needed, I have not tried. Interesting question though. If you have any further questions, I suggest to open a completely new question so we can deal with it separately.

Comment: Here's my full pom