# AspectJ: custom *.aj file is ignored

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, aspectj, spring-aop

*Why `aspectj-maven-plugin` ignore my `AnnotationInheritor.aj` file? Am I configured something wrong?*

I want to advice `ItemRepository#getById` with custom annotation:

```
@Repository
public interface ItemRepository extends JpaRepository<Item, Long> {

    // AOP does not work, since autogenerated ItemRepositoryImpl#getById 
    // won't have @MyAnnotation annotation
    @MyAnnotation 
    public Item getById(Long id);
}

@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
public @interface MyAnnotation {
}

@Aspect
@Component
public class MyAspects {

    @Around("@annotation(MyAnnotation)")
    public Object execute(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) {
        // This advice works correct when @MyAnnotation is placed on class, I tested. 
        // The problem is that I have to put @MyAnnotation on interface method
    }
}
```

Spring Data JPA use interfaces and Java annotations are never inherited from interface to subclass (due JVM limitations). To make my advice work with custom annotations [there is a little AspectJ trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42607015/emulate-annotation-inheritance-for-interfaces-and-methods-with-aspectj/42607016#42607016). So as described at previous referrence, I created `AnnotationInheritor.aj` file:

```
package com.vbakh.somepackage.aspects;

// For some reason does not work. WHY?
public aspect AnnotationInheritor { 
    declare @method : void ItemRepository+.getById() : @MyAnnotation;
}
```

And add the following configurations to my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.9</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <!-- IMPORTANT -->
                <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
                <encoding>UTF-8 </encoding>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>process-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                    <version>1.8.10</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

P.S. *Is there any way to perform the same logic without *.aj files? Means with *.java files.*

Comment: I would like to write a comprehensive answer, but am too busy right now. For the moment just check the Maven config in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41650046/1082681). You need to configure Maven Compiler and AspectJ Maven correctly and use `<phase>process-sources</phase>` for the latter. Tell me if that helps, with 16k reputation you seem to be an experienced developer. During the weekend I might be able to follow up on this with more info.

Comment: @kriegaex updated my configuration, it still does not work. Experience does not make too much sense if documentation is poor and you haven't time. I found `@DeclareAnnotation` annotation, but it hasn't been implemented yet.

Comment: I see you have verbose logging + show weave info switched on in your aspectj plugin configuration. Can you post the relevant logs as well? Is the aspect even picked up?

Comment: I know this one is old but I just found it again because my answer was upvoted. Would you mind providing some feedback and possibly accept an answer in order to close this question? You have 20k reputation and know how SO works. Three persons were trying to help you, yet there is no reaction from you.

Answer (score 2):

I copied your code into an AspectJ project (no Spring or Spring AOP there) in order to test it. I found a few problems:

- `@Around("@annotation(MyAnnotation)")` will not find the annotation because there is no fully qualified class name.
- `declare @method : void ItemRepository+.getById() : @MyAnnotation;` does not match your interface method's signature `Item getById(Long id)`.
- `MyAspects.execute(..)` needs to throw `Throwable` and of course also return something, such as the result of `joinPoint.proceed()`. But maybe that was just sloppy copy & paste.

After fixing this, the following [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) works beautifully:

**Helper classes making the project compile:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Item {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public interface JpaRepository<P, Q> {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface ItemRepository extends JpaRepository<Item, Long> {
  Item getById(Long id);
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class ItemRepositoryImpl implements ItemRepository {
  @Override
  public Item getById(Long id) {
    return new Item();
  }
}
```

**Marker annotation:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.lang.annotation.*;

@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
public @interface MyAnnotation {}
```

**Driver Application:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ItemRepository repository = new ItemRepositoryImpl();
    repository.getById(11L);
  }
}
```

**Aspects:**

Just in case you wonder why I added `execution(* *(..))` to the pointcut, this is because I wanted to exclude matching `call()` joinpoints which are available in AspectJ as opposed to Spring AOP.

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
public class MyAspect {
  @Around("@annotation(de.scrum_master.app.MyAnnotation) && execution(* *(..))")
  public Object execute(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println(joinPoint);
    return joinPoint.proceed();
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import de.scrum_master.app.Item;
import de.scrum_master.app.ItemRepository;
import de.scrum_master.app.MyAnnotation;

public aspect AnnotationInheritor {
  declare @method : Item ItemRepository+.getById(Long) : @MyAnnotation;
}
```

**Console log:**

```
execution(Item de.scrum_master.app.ItemRepositoryImpl.getById(Long))
```

Voilà! It works nicely.

If it does not work for you like this you have other issues such as (but not exclusively)

- the "auto-generated `ItemRepositoryImpl#getById`" you mentioned in passing. Whenever and wherever this is generated during the build process, it needs to exist before the aspect is applied to it. In order to analyze this I would need an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub, though.
- whether the target code to weave the aspect into is in the same Maven module as the aspect code. If it is not, you need to change your Maven setup.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it should work, even without `AnnotationInheritor`

made a small demo, have a look...

[demo](https://github.com/dirkdeyne/aspectj.git)